# Android Studio- Counting Down (If Loops) Array Errors

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio

The goal of this snippet of code is to have a runnable countdown digits on a display by decrementing milliseconds, seconds, minutes and hours

The Error i receive is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1

in relation to the following array and runnable.

```
   Integer[] RedLedDigit1 = {
            R.drawable.redled0, R.drawable.redled1,
            R.drawable.redled2, R.drawable.redled3,
            R.drawable.redled4, R.drawable.redled5,
            R.drawable.redled6, R.drawable.redled7,
            R.drawable.redled8, R.drawable.redled9 

 private Runnable timeCountDown = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                --milliseconds;

                if (milliseconds <= 0) {
                    --seconds;
                    milliseconds = 90;
                }

                if (seconds <= 0) {
                    --minutes;
                    seconds = 59;
                }

                if (minutes <= 0) {
                    --hours;
                    minutes = 59;
                }
                d8 = hours / 10;
                d7 = hours % 10;

                d6 = minutes / 10;
                d5 = minutes % 10;

                d4 = seconds / 10;
                d3 = seconds % 10;

                d2 = milliseconds / 10;
                d1 = milliseconds % 10;



            RedLed1.setImageResource(RedLedDigit1[d8]);
            RedLed2.setImageResource(RedLedDigit1[d7]);
            RedLed3.setImageResource(RedLedDigit1[d6]);
            RedLed4.setImageResource(RedLedDigit1[d5]);
            RedLed5.setImageResource(RedLedDigit1[d4]);
            RedLed6.setImageResource(RedLedDigit1[d3]);
            RedLed7.setImageResource(RedLedDigit1[d2]);
            RedLed8.setImageResource(RedLedDigit1[d1]);
            handler.postDelayed(timeCountDown, 0);
        }
    };
```

Comment: The error means you are referencing an array from outside its bounds. Your `.setImageResource` lines of code are referencing indexes of your arrays that don't exist. You likely decrement too many times or aren't properly setting up your if conditions before decrementing.

Comment: You're also missing a `}` in your array declaration